# Writing a flexible "string fetcher"

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm trying to write a module that allows for fetching of strings from an arbitrary source (e.g., an in memory list, or a file, database... whatever) so far I have:

```
type StringFetcher m = String -> m String

listStringFetcher :: [(String, String)] -> StringFetcher Maybe
listStringFetcher list key = fst <$> (listToMaybe $ filter ((key ==) . fst) list)

fileStringFetcher :: FilePath -> StringFetcher (MaybeT IO)
fileStringFetcher fp key = undefined
```

Then I suppose when I come to use it in my application I could have functions like:

```
usage :: (MonadIO m) => StringFetcher m -> m ()
usage fetch = (fetch "usage") >>= (liftIO . putStrLn)
```

But then I kind of become stuck, when I try to run `usage (listStringFetcher [("usage", "asdf")])` I get a "No instance for (MonadIO Maybe) arising from a use of `usage`" error. I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to get access to the string "inside" of the `StringFetcher`. So I feel like this approach might not be viable. Is there a more reasonable way of doing something like this?

**Edit**: To help make it a bit clearer what I'm trying to achieve, here is an actual function from my application:

```
usage :: [Command] -> ExceptT String IO String
usage c =  pure . ununlines $ [
  "usage: xyz <command>",
  "Commands:",
  unlines $ fmap (\x ->"\t" ++ name (x :: Command) ++ ": " ++ description (x :: Command)) c
  ]
```

I don't want to have the strings `"usage: xyz <command>"` and `"Commands:"` hard coded like that. What I would like to do is add another parameter to the function, whose job is to get those strings using a key. But I would like it to be possible to interchange the "String fetcher" with different implementations (which may or may not involve IO).

Comment: `I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to get access to the string "inside" of the StringFetcher.` - if I'm understanding you correctly, then you simply can't, in general. There is no general way to access the value(s) "inside" a Monad. I'm not quite sure what the intention of `fetch` is, I know the hard-coded `"usage"` is just for illustration, but there's no point writing a function unless this is a general pattern you will use a few times, in which case what to do depends on exactly how you use it, which isn't clear to me.

Comment: PS in `listStringFetcher` I think you want the outer `fst` to be `snd`

Comment: It is a general pattern I'd like to use in multiple places. The idea is to fetch strings from "anywhere" for use in the program. My idea was given the type of `StringFetcher` I should be able to use it with any monad, and within that monad use `>>=` (and friends) to do something useful with the string.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not sold on this approach at all. Or maybe I'm thinking about the whole thing completely wrong. The goal is to have functions that I can give some arbitrary StringFetcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary

This answer grew longer than I anticipated, so I think a summary is in order. For such a generic problem and rather vaguely expressed intent, the scope of solutions is rather broad. I encourage not complicating the code more than absolutely necessary, instead focusing on readability of the solution at hand. Using existing primitives like `Reader` also makes the code much less surprising for anyone else reading it. If that's still not enough, the solution at the end provides maximum flexibility in any scenario.

---

## Details

You have to understand that your StringFetcher is only a computation that might provide the value you want, but you won't get that value without actually evaluating that computation.

The problem you've hit directly is that depending on the type of StringFetcher used, the context for evaluation will depend on the value passed, meaning that, in principle, you can't use every StringFetcher in every situation. This is easier to visualize if you assume a partially-applied fetcher like so:

```
command :: forall m. StringFetcher m -> m String
command fetch = fetch "command"
```

You're not really doing any work here yet, you're just pushing the work further down the line. You're left with `m String` that requires `m` to be extracted. And you would need to make that `m` part of your signature then, somewhat like:

```
usage :: forall m. MonadIO m => StringFetcher m -> m ()
usage fetch = do
    cmdStr <- command fetch
    liftIO . putStrLn $ cmdStr
```

---

An alternative would be to avoid passing the fetcher as an argument, and instead make it a part of the context. If you know how to use `ReaderT`, this should be obvious, but anyway, for anyone else...

Assume our strings are stored in a `Map String String`. We can then leverage `Reader` to make a dependency on those strings explicit:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
type Strings = Map.Map String String 

usage :: Reader Strings ()
usage = do
    cmdStr <- fromMaybe "no description" . Map.lookup "command" <$> ask
    -- do whatever
```

Since we can't really do much "whatever" in this particular function, we need `ReaderT` to augment it a bit:

```
usage :: ReaderT Strings IO ()
usage = do
    cmdStr <- fromMaybe "no description" . Map.lookup "command" <$> ask
    liftIO . putStrLn $ cmdStr
```

Presto! We now have an explicit dependency to both the `Strings` and the IO, and the strings can be provided from outside on demand. Which is sort of where the magic happens:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let strings = Map.fromList [("command", "this is a command")]
    runReaderT usage strings
```

For your case, instead of `Reader Strings` you might simply want to create your own type with `askForCommand` that would shorten this code a bit and make it more explicit.

The thing is, it's sort of silly to jump through all those hoops if you assume there's gonna be an IO variant of the fetcher somewhere. If that's the case, you might simply assume it always needs IO, and in the case of predefined string list it just won't touch it. This will massively simplify the implementation without any real loss.

If you do *insist* on changing the actual type of the (focus here) code using the Fetcher basing on the Fetcher itself (e.g. `usage` using pure fetcher is pure, while `usage` using IO fetcher is IO<sup>1</sup>), you need a Transformer Monad Class:

```
usage :: forall m. => (MonadStringFetcher m, MonadIO) -> m ()
```

This example is admittedly pretty silly if `usage` is using IO anyway (goes to what I said before as well), but in case it didn't, it wouldn't have to.

Again, `MonadReader` class could serve as a good template for implementing it. This approach is very similar to "effects" (as seen e.g. in Idris) and allows you to directly build the context type from the expected capabilities. It's the most flexible way of writing such stuff, but also the most time-consuming and getting complex really quickly once start adding more stuff.

---

<sup>1</sup> This talks about the requirements for `usage` carried over from the Fetcher, and not its internals like in case of `putStrLn` I used. You might think about two different `IO`s here.

Comment: The reader seems like it could be what I want, but I guess I'm doing something silly, because GHC doesn't seem to like `usage :: ReaderT IO Strings ()` - "Expecting one or more argument to IO" Edit: Looks like the arguments are just the wrong way around, `ReaderT String IO ()` works.

Comment: Yup, the reader monad transformer looks like it does what I want. I never read much about the reader monad, time to look in to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it won't answer directly you question, but could be a guide. A concrete instance of your function example would be:

```
usage ::  StringFetcher IO -> IO ()
usage fetch = (fetch "usage") >>= ((liftIO . putStrLn) :: String -> IO ())
```

and that leads to the error:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe String’ with ‘IO String’
      Expected type: StringFetcher IO
        Actual type: StringFetcher Maybe
    • In the first argument of ‘usage’, namely
        ‘(listStringFetcher [("usage", "asdf")])’
      In the expression: usage (listStringFetcher [("usage", "asdf")])
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = usage (listStringFetcher [("usage", "asdf")])
```

meaning with your current definition of `listStringFetcher` will never work with `liftIO` because its type is well, IO, not Maybe.

Either you use another function, not `liftIO`, or change the definition of the other function

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is making me see I'm thinking about it wrong and this approach can't work the way I want it to. Maybe I need to consider type classes or something...